# Recent badge notification spam

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, notifications

So starting from when I flagged a post until now every time I visit any SO site after a few minutes I get a few notifications (never more) stating that I have earned the Citizen Patrol badge, yet I never actually receive the badge. It's not that annoying, but it's still a bug.

[image]

The flagged post has been removed, which is why I earned the badge I suppose, but if it is any help the flagged post (which was an answer) was located here: [No Man's Sky: Finding Zinc on a dead moon - without a spaceship](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/282831/no-mans-sky-finding-zinc-on-a-dead-moon-without-a-spaceship)

This was the first ever flag I have raised in Arcade SO and since then I have not posted anything or raised any more flags.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yeah we're all getting it. It's a current bug, here's the main report on Meta.SE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283748/badge-notification-repeats

Comment: @Robotnik oh lol - totally missed that, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My fault. Isn't it always? We had a problem with badges failing to award last night, so I added some extra logging to capture more info when it stumbled. In the process I accidentally broke something such that it *appeared* to work, but really didn't actually do anything. Deploying the fix now. Sorry folks.

Comment: Can confirm it now works. I just received the badge.

Comment: Thanks @Marc :-)